# Typescript doesn't select the correct overload

Tags: typescript, mongoose

- typescript version: 2.1.4
- @types/mongoose version: 4.7.1

I use mongoose's types:

```js
post<T extends Document>(method: string, fn: (
  error: mongodb.MongoError, doc: T, next: (err?: NativeError) => void
) => void): this;

post<T extends Document>(method: string, fn: (
  doc: T, next: (err?: NativeError) => void
) => void): this;
```

in my code:

```js
function (schema: Schema) {
  schema.post('remove', function (doc, next) { });
}
```

It always choose first `post` define, `doc` will be `mongodb.MongoError`, `next` will be `T`.

Did I miss something?
  and how to make it choose second `post` define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript always selects the *first* overload that matches the specified parameters. Because function arguments may be ignored by the callee, this means that functions accepting callbacks of higher arity should come *after* callbacks of lower arity.

The second overload is more specific (it can handle a function of *lower* total arity than the previous overload), so the second overload should be listed above the first one in this case.

TL;DR: .d.ts file has a bug, those two `post` lines should be swapped.